# Installing MAVROS package on ROS melodic & Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ros, ubuntu-18.04

when trying to run a ROS script to spawn uavs, I got following error message. Installed ROS Melodic, Ubuntu 18.04, all seemed fine...

```
Resource not found: mavros
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/melodic/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/home/jakub/git/simulation/install/share/simulation
ROS path [2]=/home/jakub/git/simulation/install/share/simulation
ROS path [3]=/opt/ros/melodic/share
ROS path [4]=/usr/share
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

Comment: I think you're better off asking this on https://askubuntu.com/

Comment: Thanks for suggestion

Comment: Post launch file(s) Please. Also Have you installed Mavros ???

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is about the environment variables. Try to set them in the `~/.bashrc` file

```
px4_dir=~/Firmware
source /opt/ros/noetic/setup.bash
source ~/drone_ws/devel/setup.bash
source $px4_dir/Tools/setup_gazebo.bash $px4_dir $px4_dir/build/px4_sitl_default
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH:$px4_dir
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH:$px4_dir/Tools/sitl_gazebo
export GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH=$GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gazebo-11/plugins
```